# Unable to call jersey webservice from jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jersey

Hi i developed a web service that based on jersey 1.8 restful .
when i invoked webservice from browser like 
`http://localhost:8080/EC/EC/loginValidate/epicSearch/IVE0016808` i got output like

```
{"name":"Aneel Kumar Ravula","pollingStationLocation":"MARRIPALLI MPP SCHOOL","gender":"male","age":23,}
```

But when i invoked from jquery ajax it fails and controll at  error function.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {
            // fetch some more records from the server side
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "json",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/EC/EC/loginValidate/epicSearch/IVE0016808",
                success: function(){alert('sucess by anil')},
                error: function(event){alert('fail by anilevent '+event)}
            });

    });
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

now this is my latest code  how to get response

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.support.cors = true;
            // fetch some more records from the server side
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType : "JSON",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/EC/EC/loginValidate/epicSearch/IVE0016808",
                crossDomain : true ,
                success: function(resp){alert('sucess by anil'+resp)},
                error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, errorThrown){alert('fail by anilevent '+errorThrown)}
            });

    });
```

Comment: Do you really need crossDomain: true for localhost?

Comment: actually not neede but i tried with different options forgot to remove

Comment: take out the contentType as well or change it to dataType

Comment: tried no use as json no use same error

Comment: Error callback has 3 parameters. jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown.  Add all three of those and output the errorThrown string.  Add the error you are getting to the post.

Comment: place debugger, and provide the exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I think your ajax call should look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;

        // fetch some more records from the server side
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/EC/EC/loginValidate/epicSearch/IVE0016808",
            success: function(data){alert('sucess by anil: ' + data.name)},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert('fail by anilevent '+errorThrown)}
        });

});
```

Comment: Try to add jQuery.support.cors = true;  Updated post.

Comment: resp is [object objeect] how to get data

Comment: That sounds right.  if you have success: function(data){ alert(data.name);} it should output your name.  (or whatever property you want to output)

Comment: If you need it to work in mozilla you may need to change the webservice to return jsonp instead of just json.  See http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/